# Adding a comment to a database field using JET

Tags: php, ms-access, jet

I am working on a script to manage a small Access database online using the Jet engine in PHP. One thing I am having trouble doing is adding a comment to a field. This is quite easy using Access directly, but I can't figure out to do it programatically through an SQL statement or something similar. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I generally use MySQL, but Access provides a few benefits from time to time for smaller databases. Mostly, I can download and email them to people to use for whatever purpose they require.

I store timestamps as a `long int` rather than one of the built in types because it is easier to work with in PHP that way, and a lot easier to run a query against. I want to add a simple comment next to these timestamp fields that simply says something like `Unix Timestamp` so both the script and user know this as a timestamp rather than simply a number. I already know how to read comments, but can't seem to figure out how to write them when adding a new field.

I am using ADODB and Jet to interact with the database like so:

```
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={$db};Mode=ReadWrite;");
```

Comment: I doubt it's standard sql, but mysql has a 'comment' option for DDL. `alter table foo add bar int comment "this is my field comment"`. Google fails me on this for Access, but perhaps BillCo has built in something equivalent for Jet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at the desciption with an ADOX Catalog, [which, it seems, can be used with PHP](http://pear.php.net/package/DB_ado/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_DB_ado__DB_ado-1.3.1ado.php.html)

In VBA you could say:

```
catdb.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & CurrentProject.FullName

catdb.Tables("ATable").Columns("AColumn").Properties("Description") = "New descr"
```

Comment: That looks great for programming Access, ASP, or the likes, but I am having trouble getting a working version in PHP. I'll keep at it, but any insights would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @steveo255 I thought the link was about PHP and ADOX, is it of no use?

Comment: This does not seem to be possible with PHP, however, this solution does seem to work with ASP, so I am going to accept it. Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but probably the best answer I would ever get. Thanks for the help.